# Regex start and end with same string, not just same character

Tags: javascript, regex, rex

I want to create a regular expression to receive:

```
<p class="MyClass">
   <p> something 1 </p>
   <p> something 2 </p>
   <span>         <span>  // or more html tag here
   something
</p>
something's here, not in any tag!
```

from:

```
<p class="MyClass">
   <p> something 1 </p>
   <p> something 2 </p>
   <span>         <span>  // or more html tag here
   something
</p>
something's here, not in any tag!

<p class="MyClass">
   <p> another thing 1</p>
   <p> another thing 2</p>
   <p> another thing 3</p>
   another thing
</p>
...
```

I think I will use a regex to match everything between `<p class="MyClass">` and the next one. So the regex is `/(<p class="MyClass">[\s\S]*)<p class="MyClass">/`, work correctly in this case. But it doesn't work when I want to get a notification of this page http://daotao.dut.udn.vn/sv/G_Thongbao_LopHP.aspx. The DOM is so strange ?!

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Is the HTML a string on it is in DOM?

Comment: It is in DOM. @Tushar

Comment: I wanna get some of notifications in this page http://daotao.dut.udn.vn/sv/G_Thongbao_LopHP.aspx, but the DOM of this page is so strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex should be

```
(<p class="MyClass">[\s\S]*?)(?=<p class="MyClass">|$)
```

- `[\s\S]*?` : `*?` is a lazy quantifier so that it matches the shortest the default is greedy (matches the largest).
- `(?=<p class="MyClass">|$)`: lookhead so that it does not  belongs to the match, and `|$` to get also the last match